# Use mustache.js to iterate through one quiz item at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, mustache

I'm trying to make a quiz application using JQuery, JSON, and Mustache.js, but I'm having some trouble.

I can get Mustache.js to print out my entire set of JSON objects, no problem, but I'm wondering if there's a way I can get it to only print out one set of objects at a time. For instance, I would like the quiz app to display one question and its corresponding set of possible answers (in radio button form), then when a user selects an answer and presses the "next" button, the next question and set of answers will appear and replace the previous answers.

As it stands, I currently have JQuery making an AJAX call to my json file, and mustache.js pulling all records in and displaying them in a series of p tags (for the questions) and ul tags (for the answers). So for now, is there some way I can get it to only grab one question at a time?

Here is what I currently have in my script. Please note, this is a work in progress.

```
$(function(){
    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data){ //Make AJAX call to server
        var template = "{{#quiz}}" + //Create mustashe js template
            "<div class='quizarea'>" +
                "<p>{{question}}</p>" +
                "<ul>" +
                    "{{#answers}}" +
                        "<li>{{text}}</li>" +
                    "{{/answers}}" +
                "</ul>" +
            "</div>" +
        "{{/quiz}}";
        var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);//Turn template into usable html
        $('#quizpane').html(html);//Send html to the quizpane div
    });//get JSON
});//end function
```

The example can be found at http://jamesdauer.com/javascript/quiz/

Maybe Mustache.js isn't even the way to go? I was thinking I might try and use handlebars or ember, but I don't know that those would do what I'm looking to do any better. I really appreciate any help you folks can give. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First a few changes to your code should be made.
1. The javascript:

```
$(function () {
var template = "<div class='quizarea'>" +
    "<p>{{question}}</p>" +
    "<ul>" +
    "{{#answers}}" +
    "<li>{{text}}</li>" +
    "{{/answers}}" +
    "</ul>" +
    "</div>";
var count = 0;
render = function () {
    var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data.quiz[count]);
    $('#quizpane').html(html);
};
render();
$("#next-question").click(function () {
    count++;
    render();
});
});
```

2 . In the HTML :

```
    <div id='quizpane'></div>
    <button name="next" id="next-question">Next question</button>
```

note that the I changed the template and added a counter to the javascript to keep track at which question you are currently, and instead of sending the entire `data` object to `render()` you sent the current question `data.quiz[count]`

On fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/aBNVJ/1/